# Command Blocks Minecraft Placing A Command WIth Commands In It

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is not a repeat of another post, as I am having a specific problem which is really annoying me.

I am getting an error saying that there is a character that is not supposed to be there in my command, but I can't find it.

Command:

```
/setblock -248 33 642 command_block 0 replace {Command:"testfor @a[score_craft_min=1] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:cobblestone"}]}"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotation mark directly after `id:` is closing the `Command` string. The next character is then an 'm', which is unexpected and throws an error. You must escape the quotes to tell the parser to skip them:

```
/setblock -248 33 642 command_block 0 replace {Command:"testfor @a[score_craft_min=1] {Inventory:[{id:\"minecraft:cobblestone\"}]}"}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot!!!! I didn't know I had to do that! thx :)